# Access: Counting unique records in two joined tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables that look like this:

```
Rep     Client ID #
-------------------
Bob     100
Joe     200
Joe     201
Dave    300
Dave    301

Rep     Client ID #
----------------
Jack    100
Joe     200
Joe     400
Dave    300
Dave    500
```

I need to do two things:

1. Count how many clients (ID #'s) are assigned to each rep in each table. E.g. for table 1 it would be Bob has 1, Joe has 2, and Dave has 2.
2. Count how many total UNIQUE clients each rep has, from both tables. In the example above it would be Bob has 1, Joe has 3, Dave has 3, and Jack has 1.

How can I do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the count of distinct clientids per rep per table you can use:

```
SELECT
    sourcetable,
    rep,
    count(clientid)
FROM    
    (
        SELECT
            "table 1" as [sourcetable],
            rep,
            clientid
        FROM 
            table1
        GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT
    sourcetable,
    rep,
    count(clientid)
FROM    
    (
        SELECT
            "table 2" as [sourcetable],
            rep,
            clientid
        FROM 
            table2
        GROUP BY 1,2,3
    )
```

To get just the count of distinct clientids for each rep without regard to the table:

```
SELECT
    rep,
    count(clientid)
FROM
    (
        SELECT rep,clientid FROM table1
        UNION
        SELECT rep,clientid FROM table2
    )
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY`/`Totals` Query. For your first requirement,

```
SELECT 
    Rep,
    Count(ClientID) As CountOfID
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY 
    Rep;
```

For your second requirement. You will need a UNION with GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
    TmpQ.Rep,
    Count(TmpQ.ClientID) As CountOfID
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Table1.Rep,
            Table1.ClientID
        FROM 
            Table1
        GROUP BY 
            Table1.Rep,
            Table1.ClientID
        UNION
        SELECT
            Table2.Rep,
            Table2.ClientID
        FROM 
            Table2
        GROUP BY 
            Table2.Rep,
            Table2.ClientID
    ) As TmpQ
GROUP BY 
    TmpQ.Rep;
```

Comment: Thank you. This and JNevill's answer below are very similar. For the second requirement, in the inner query with the union, don't I need to toss out duplicates somehow? The union will just append the two queries together, no? If the same client ID is in both tables assigned to the same rep, I should only count it once. How do I do that?

Comment: UNION, ignores the duplicated from the two tables on making them one. So what existed in **Table1**, if it reoccurs in **Table2**, it will not be included. So only UNIQUE Values will be in TmpQ. So when you run my Query, you will get the right counts.